# Adding value from JSON to minichart Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I have a JSON layer from my GeoServer and I want to create a barchart using Minichart from Leaflet. Now I want to parse one of the properties of the layer as a value to show on the chart.

How can I call the properties? With my code it doesnt work.

```
    var states =
        "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=cite:State&outputFormat=application/json&srsName=epsg:4326";
        $.getJSON(states).then((res) => {
        var layer = L.geoJson(res, {
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                layer.on('click', function (e) {
                    window.location.replace(e.target.feature.properties.win_url);
                })
            },
            style: polystates,
        }).addTo(map);

        
    });

var options = {data:[feature.properties.geasmt_strom]}


var barChartMarker = L.minichart(map.getCenter(),options);
```

EDIT:

```
        var states =
        "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=cite:State&outputFormat=application/json&srsName=epsg:4326";
    $.getJSON(states).then((res) => {
        var layer = L.geoJson(res, {
            //onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
               // layer.on('click', function (e) {
                 //   window.location.replace(e.target.feature.properties.win_url);
                //})
            //},
            style: polystates,
        }).addTo(map);            
    });
    
    

d = states
var barchart=L.minichart(map.getCenter(),{data:d.geasmt_strom});
barchart.addTo(map);
```

With the above code it is showing me something on my map at least. But just a bar chart with one bar.

[image]

```
    var states =
        "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=cite:State&outputFormat=application/json&srsName=epsg:4326";
   $.getJSON(states).then((res) => {
        var layer = L.geoJson(res, {
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            layer.on('click', function (e) {
             window.location.replace(e.target.feature.properties.win_url);
                })
           },
            
            style: polystates,
                   
    });
    
    states.addTo(map);
```

With the code above the layer is not showing up.

```
   var states =
        "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=cite:State&outputFormat=application/json&srsName=epsg:4326";
        $.getJSON(states).then((res) => {
        var layer = L.geoJson(res, {
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                layer.on('click', function (e) {
                    window.location.replace(e.target.feature.properties.win_url);
                })
            },
            style: polystates,
        }).addTo(map);

        
    });
```

With the code above I get the following result:

[image]

Comment: What do you see/get if you add your GeoJSON layer as separate map layer? Please add image of that.

Comment: When I call it outside of the var states = .... with states.addTo(map); then it is not adding the layer to the map. Do I have to save the layer differently?

Comment: Please add also an example of GeoJSON feature returned from AJAX call. I suppose you want to display bar representing feature property `geasmt_strom` in the middle of each feature?

Comment: Yes I want to representing the property geasmt_strom in the middle of the feature. Sorry I dont understand what are you asking for. What do you mean with returned from AJAX call? I thought this is what I am doing already... Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mini charts have to be created separately for every feature. Since charts are separate, `maxValues` option has to be used to scale them to the same denominator. This means all values have to be saved into some array first end then max value found.

To display mini chart in the center of the feature, feature centroid has to be calculated, which can be done using [turf.js](https://turfjs.org/) `turf.centroid` method.

Code could then look something like this:

```
var states = "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=cite:State&outputFormat=application/json&srsName=epsg:4326";

var coords = [];
var values = [];
 
$.getJSON(states).then((res) => {
  var layer = L.geoJson(res, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
      var centroid = turf.centroid(feature);
      var coord = turf.getCoord(centroid);
      coords.push(coord);
      values.push(feature.properties.geasmt_strom);
      layer.on('click', function (e) {
        window.location.replace(e.target.feature.properties.win_url);
      })
    },
    style: polystates,
  }).addTo(map);
  
    var maxValue = Math.max(...values);
    coords.forEach(function(coord, i) {
    L.minichart([coord[1], coord[0]], {data: [values[i]], maxValues: maxValue}).addTo(map);
  });
});
```

Have in mind that `L.minichart` plugin currently does not work in the latest Leaflet 1.9.x.